# Android swapping between to activities

Tags: java, android

Can any one please tell me how can i swap between two activities horizontally. Once user swap screen to left the next activity will load. As i am beginner so please tell me the easiest way to achieve it.

Comment: You may want to add what you've tried and add more detail if you want people to be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it would be better having only one `Activity` and using `Fragment` in conjunction with a `ViewPager` to achieve the desired effect.

The [official training page](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) on the subject explains this better than I could.

If you are not familiar with the concept of Fragment, there is also a training section on that [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html).

Finally, since you are a beginner, I would recommend you go through most of the official training or any other complete training support such as [Mark Murphy's Busy Coder’s Guide to Android Development](http://commonsware.com/Android/) or [Reto Meier's Professional Android 4 Application Development](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118102274.html).

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for the [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) component. This will allow you to swipe between screens. Please note you will have to implement the different screens as `Fragments` though.

There is a guide on this in the docs: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html